# How to get local storage value in razor page condition using c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, razor

We have form with password, we have restricted page, also we store value in `localstorage`
but how can we get localStorage value in razor page condition with c#.

**Page1**. `localStorage.setItem("isDirected", "false")`

Comment: I don't think it's possible since razor is executed at the server level and localStorage is at the client level.

Comment: then what could be the possible alternative solution?@Arcord

Comment: I don't know the usage but couldn't you provide the password in the next request to your server ?

Comment: not possible may be "correct" but if one really needs it and one can't use blazor then I think it should be possible if you open a socket connection, like a chat, and have the server call and query the client. it would be a performance killer but, possible. have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications